# i need a little help ): with constructors in apex class

Tags: apex, constructor

```
public class OrderItemWrapper{  
 @AuraEnabled  
 public string orderItemName;
 @AuraEnabled  
 public decimal orderItemQuantity;
 @AuraEnabled  
 public decimal orderItemAvailableQuantity;
 @AuraEnabled  
 public String orderItemSKU;
 @AuraEnabled  
 public String orderItemPatientFillId;  

 public OrderItemWrapper(OrderItem orderItemObj){  
   this.orderItemName = orderItemObj.Product_Name__c;
   this.orderItemQuantity=orderItemObj.Quantity;
   this.orderItemAvailableQuantity=orderItemObj.AvailableQuantity;
   this.orderItemSKU=orderItemObj.Product2.StockKeepingUnit;
   this.orderItemPatientFillId=orderItemObj.Prescription_Link__r.Patient_Fill_Id__c;
 }  
}
```

i want to make a apex class to make a new OrderItemWrapper, but i don't know how get the method  i have this done but it isn´t correct and it was the way i understood this, i'm new help me whith this please

```
static testMethod void fakeTest(){
    
    ControllerOrderSummary order = new ControllerOrderSummary();
    
    
    ControllerOrderSummary.OrderItemWrapper item = OrderItemWrapper(new OrderItem);
    
        item.orderItemAvailableQuantity = (23.3);
        item.orderItemName = ('Paracetamol');
        item.orderItemQuantity = (22.3);
    
    
    
    
 ControllerOrderSummary.fakeMethod(); //method invocation
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct an object, you need to write `new SomeClass()`; it needs the `()` if there is a zero-argument constructor, or any extra parameters if the constructor needs them. In the case of an sObject, you can initialize the fields in the constructor, too. To construct an object in other class, you also still need to use the `OuterName.InnerName` syntax. Finally, note that `testMethod` is deprecated, you should use `@isTest` instead.

```
@isTest static void fakeTest(){
    ControllerOrderSummary order = new ControllerOrderSummary();
    ControllerOrderSummary.OrderItemWrapper item = new ControllerOrderSummary.OrderItemWrapper(
        new OrderItem(
            Product_Name__c='Paracetamol', 
            Quantity=22.3, 
            AvailableQuantity=23.3
        )
    );
    ControllerOrderSummary.fakeMethod(); //method invocation
}
```

Note that if you need to assign `item` to a property in `ControllerOrderSummary` if that method needs the data.